# How to pass a value to Django-Modelform in InputHidden IntegerField without even disturbing visible field in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I created a Django model with three fields in which one of them is hidden and rest of them are visible

```
1.CharField
2.IntegerField (Hidden Field)
3.DateTimeField
```

I made this hidden by using following code :

```
class HostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Host
        widgets = {
            'Zone_Vale': forms.HiddenInput()
          }
```

To view this form, i am using following code in my temlate:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Add host" %}" />
```

Everything is fine but i want to pass a variable in this input hidden layer also. I a not getting any idea to do this. I tried to do by customizing the template (refer this link:) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ `
For example {{ form.as_p}} will return a form containing two visible field and the data into them is :(what user had entered it) and a hidden field. So, I want to pass a variable to that hidden field from template.html file

It doesn't work also. Need your help

Comment: From where do you want to pass the variable ? What doesn't work ? http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel like being dirty, a fast solution is to populate this field using javascript. The right way should be using the "initial" parameter when instantiating the form object at view.py

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial

Even being **very dirty**, some javascript solution like this shoud work too:
(using jQuery. Adapt for your needs)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form input[name$="Zone_Vale"]').val(DESIRED_HIDDEN_VALUE)
    })
</script>
```

But don't be proud of being doing that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already mentioned in my post that i only want to pass a value only from the template not at the time of checking forms. So the "initial" parameter will not work :)

I have a java script variable how can i pass to that hidden field. If i am not wrong then there is only one thing to do i.e pass in template and i am not able to figure that. Waiting for your reply :)

Comment: Use javascript for populating that field. Pass the form prefix+id to the template by context and use that to get the input field. Then set the value.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to pass a variable to the field at the template level, given how you're rendering the template.

If you really, absolutely must pass a variable to the form at the template level, I would suggest creating a template tag that will:

1. Resolve your variable from the request context
2. Instantiate the form class using the variable as part of the initial data for the form
3. Add the form to the context to be rendered